# customising serialisation of java collections using xstream

Tags: java, collections, xml-serialization, xstream

I have an object that needs to be serialised as XML, which contains the following field:

```
List<String> tags = new List<String>();
```

XStream serialises it just fine (after some aliases) like this:

```
<tags>
  <string>tagOne</string>
  <string>tagTwo</string>
  <string>tagThree</string>
  <string>tagFour</string>
</tags>
```

That's OK as far as it goes, but I'd like to be able to rename the `<string>` elements to, say, `<tag>`. I can't see an obvious way to do that from the alias documentation on the XStream site. Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd suggest changing the `List<String>` to a `List<Tag>`, where Tag is a domain object that essentially just contains a String.  Then you say:

```
xstream.alias("tag", org.goring.Tag.class);
```

and you get exactly what you want.  This avoids having to roll your own Converter.

Comment: That's exactly what I ended up doing about half an hour ago. Worked a treat. :)

Comment: Could you please elaborate on how the Tag class could be? If I keep a string variable (say tagValue) in it, I get something like <tags><tag><tagValue>tagOne</tagValue></tag><tag><tagValue>tagTwo</tagValue></tag></tags>. Thanks in advance.

Comment: As Jonna says above, I don't think this will give you the output you want, unless I'm missing something. I've just tried it and found the same as Jonna. The solution below using the CollectionConverter and ClassAliasingMapper did what I needed in only 3 lines of code though.

Answer (score 12):

Out of interest I gave it a try to do it without writing my own converter. Basically I just register a special instructed version of `CollectionConverter` for a certain field in a certain class.

Relevant snippet:

```
ClassAliasingMapper mapper = new ClassAliasingMapper(xstream.getMapper());
mapper.addClassAlias("tag", String.class);
xstream.registerLocalConverter(
    Test.class,
    "tags",
    new CollectionConverter(mapper)
);
```

Full-blown example:

```
import com.thoughtworks.xstream.*;
import com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.*;
import com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Test {
    public List<String> tags = new ArrayList<String>();
    public List<String> notags = new ArrayList<String>();
    public Test(String tag, String tag2) {
        tags.add(tag); tags.add(tag2);
        notags.add(tag); notags.add(tag2);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test test = new Test("foo", "bar");
        XStream xstream = new XStream();

        ClassAliasingMapper mapper = new ClassAliasingMapper(xstream.getMapper());
        mapper.addClassAlias("tag", String.class);
        xstream.registerLocalConverter(
            Test.class,
            "tags",
            new CollectionConverter(mapper)
        );

        System.out.println(xstream.toXML(test));
    }
}
```

---

Not tested but this should work. No?

```
xstream.alias("tag", java.lang.String.class);
```

Comment: It does work (I just tried it,) but it picks up and aliases the members of any <em>other</em> Collection of Strings in the class as well. Unfortunately in my real class (unlike the example) there is more than one such Collection.

Comment: This solution works perfectly. Tested on XStream 1.3.1.

Will > how is it possible? this kind of aliasing is done only on field "tags" of Test class and every other collection in Test class is aliased by default settings of XStream mappers (ie. they have same xml representation as you write in your initial post -> <tags> <string>...</string></tags>).

Comment: Will Gorings comment relates to the first version of my answer. Which is the oneliner below the horizontal line

Answer (score 2):

```
@XStreamAlias("example")
public class A {
    private B myList;

    public A(){
        this.myList = new B();
    }

    public A clone(){
        A a = new A();
        a.myList = this.myList;
        return a;
    }

    public B getMyList() {
        return myList;
    }

    public void setMyList(B myList) {
        this.myList = myList;
    }   
}

public class B {
    @XStreamImplicit(itemFieldName = "myField")
    ArrayList<String> myFieldlist;

    public B(){
        this.myFieldlist = new ArrayList<String>();
    }

    public B clone(){
        B b = new B();
        b.myFieldlist = this.myFieldlist;
        return b;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getMyFieldlist() {
            return myFieldlist;
    }

    public void setMyFieldlist(ArrayList<String> myFieldlist) {
        this.myFieldlist = myFieldlist;
    }
}


public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A a = new A();
        a.getMyList().getMyFieldlist().add("aa");
        a.getMyList().getMyFieldlist().add("bb");       

        XStream xs = new XStream(new DomDriver());  
        xs.processAnnotations(A.class);
        xs.processAnnotations(B.class);     

        System.out.println(xs.toXML(a));                
    }
}
```

xml result:

```
<example>
  <myList>
    <myField>aa</myField>
    <myField>bb</myField>
  </myList>
</example>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add alias for the `java.util.String` class. Okay, that may break something else elsewhere but in this exact case that should be enough.

If you don't want to do the thing above, you can make your own converters ([see this handy tutorial](http://xstream.codehaus.org/converter-tutorial.html)) which will help you achieve your goal. And don't be afraid of making your own converter either, they're really easy to implement.

Comment: Gotcha. I'd hoped to avoid writing my own Converter, since the class in question has a tonne of fields, but if that's what I have to do...

Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
@XStreamConverter(value=ListToStringXStreamConverter.class, strings={"tag"})
List<String> tags = new List<String>();
```

and in ListToStringXStreamConverter.java

```
public class ListToStringXStreamConverter implements Converter {

private String alias;

public ListToStringXStreamConverter(String alias) {
    super();
    this.alias = alias;
}

@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
@Override
public boolean canConvert(Class type) {
    return true;
}

@Override
public void marshal(Object source, HierarchicalStreamWriter writer, MarshallingContext context) {

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    List<String> list = (List<String>)source;

    for (String string : list) {
        writer.startNode(alias);
        writer.setValue(string);
        writer.endNode();
    }

}

@Override
public Object unmarshal(HierarchicalStreamReader reader, UnmarshallingContext context) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("ListToStringXStreamConverter does not offer suport for unmarshal operation");
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

for me works with the code below, using Strings:

```
xStream.alias("myTag", Person.class);
xStream.addImplicitCollection(Person.class, "myTag", "myTag", String.class);
```

```
public class Person{
    private ArrayList<String> myTag;
    // ...
}
```

```
<Person>
      <myTag>atrcxb2102</myTag>
      <myTag>sub3</myTag>
</Person>
```