# How do I rename XStream list elements?

Tags: java, xml-serialization, xstream

I have a model that looks like:

```
@XStreamAlias("article")
class Article {
  List<String> tags;
  List<String> categories;
}
```

XStream serializes to XML that looks like:

```
<article>
  <tags>
    <string>foo</string>
  </tags>
  <categories>
    <string>bar</string>
  </categories>
</article>
```

My question is how can I make it so that `<string>foo</string>` becomes `<tag>foo<tag>` and `<string>bar</string>` becomes `<category>bar</category>`?  I'm unable to change the structure of my model since I am using the Morphia ODM to create the Article instances (article must contain `List<String>`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1791178/customising-serialisation-of-java-collections-using-xstream) may be of use to you.

Nutshell version:

```
ClassAliasingMapper mapper = new ClassAliasingMapper(stream.getMapper());
mapper.addClassAlias("tag", String.class);
mapper.addClassAlias("category", String.class);
stream.registerLocalConverter(Article.class, "tags", new CollectionConverter(mapper));
stream.registerLocalConverter(Article.class, "categories", new CollectionConverter(mapper));
```

Answer (score 1):

In XStream version 1.4.5 you need to define different mapper objects for different class alias. The solution will be as following:

```
    ClassAliasingMapper mapper = new ClassAliasingMapper(xstream.getMapper());  

    //tag
    mapper.addClassAlias("tag", String.class);
    xstream.registerLocalConverter(
        Article.class,
        "tags",
        new CollectionConverter(mapper)
    );


    mapper = new ClassAliasingMapper(xstream.getMapper()); 
          // this is required otherwise it will override the previos mapper
    mapper.addClassAlias("category", String.class);
    xstream.registerLocalConverter(
        Article.class,
        "categories",
        new CollectionConverter(mapper)
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

Out of my mind:

```
@XStreamImplicit(itemFieldName="tag")
private List<String> categoryList;
```

Does it work?

Comment: That doesn't work.  That just removes the parent `<tags>` element.

Comment: @Hokiedood Sorry then I do not know the answer, possibly someone else does